# Android4.3 以降のデフォルトブラウザでbackground-size:coverは使えない？

Tags: css

Android4.3ブラウザで`background-size:cover;`の適応が確認できなかったため質問させていただきます。

`background-size:cover;`と、`background-size: auto 100%;`を使って確認したのですが、適応されていませんでした。

GooglePlayから、GoogleChromeをインストールを行い確認したところ、適応されていました。

Androidブラウザでは、`background-size`はサポートされていないのでしょうか？

`<img>`に変更すれば簡単に解決されるとは思いますが、動的な処理で`background-image`が生成されており、私の技術力では変更できません。

どうにかしてbackgroundで画面幅いっぱいに表示する方法はございませんでしょうか？

初歩的な問題ではございますが、お力添えお願いいたします。

以下は実際の指定しているコードです。

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    -moz-background-size: auto 100% !important;
    -webkit-background-size: auto 100% !important;
    -o-background-size: auto 100% !important;
    -ms-background-size: auto 100% !important;
    background-size:  auto 100% !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #777;
}
```

ー 問題を確認した端末 ー
・SamsungGalaxyS4 4.3
・HTC Evo 4.2.2

Comment: [バグ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720922/background-sizecover-leaves-blank-space-in-chrome-for-android)のようですね。リンク先含めてちゃんと読んでいませんので、もし質問者さんの方で解決の糸口がみつかれば共有していただけるとありがたいです。